# Route transform does not work when using curly bracket

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

I have the following codes

`Startup.cs`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.Add(new RouteTokenTransformerConvention(new SlugifyParameterTransformer()));
    });
}
```

where `SlugifyParameterTransformer` implements `IOutboundParameterTransformer` and transform URL to SEO-friendly URL.

In my `HomeController`, I have these

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[Route("{controller}/{action}")]   // Route transform ONLY work when using square bracket.
public IActionResult SomeTestPage()
{
    return View();
}
```

In my `Index.cshtml`, I have these

```xml
@addTagHelper *,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SomeTestPage">Some Test Page</a>
```

Upon build and running the web site, the URL to `SomeTestPage` is `localhost\Home\SomeTestPage` which is not transformed by `SlugifyParameterTransformer`. However, the URL gets transformed properly to `localhost\home\some-test-page` after I replaced curly bracket to square bracket in the `RouteAttribute` decorating `SomeTestPage` action method.

What is the difference between curly bracket and square bracket when defining route template with attribute routing?

Comment: Which .NET Core version of your project?

Comment: @FeiHan I'm using ASP.NET Core 5.0

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between curly bracket and square bracket when defining route template with attribute routing?

In [official example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area), we can find that it usually uses `[controller]`, `[action]`, `[area]` with square-brackets for the controller name, action name and area name, and use `{id}` etc for other generic route parameters in attribute routes.

Besides, as @serpent5 mentioned in [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/20988#issuecomment-751521482), an `IOutboundParameterTransformer` seems process only `[` and `]` when used with attribute routing.

*[Source code of `ReplaceTokens` method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/5.0/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ApplicationModels/AttributeRouteModel.cs#L270) that replaces the tokens in the template with the provided values and route token transformer*

```
/// <summary>
/// Replaces the tokens in the template with the provided values and route token transformer.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="template">The template.</param>
/// <param name="values">The token values to use.</param>
/// <param name="routeTokenTransformer">The route token transformer.</param>
/// <returns>A new string with the replaced values.</returns>
public static string ReplaceTokens(string template, IDictionary<string, string> values, IOutboundParameterTransformer routeTokenTransformer)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var state = TemplateParserState.Plaintext;

    int? tokenStart = null;
    var scope = 0;

    // We'll run the loop one extra time with 'null' to detect the end of the string.
    for (var i = 0; i <= template.Length; i++)
    {
        var c = i < template.Length ? (char?)template[i] : null;
        switch (state)
        {
            case TemplateParserState.Plaintext:
                if (c == '[')
                {
                    scope++;
                    state = TemplateParserState.SeenLeft;
                    break;
                }
                else if (c == ']')
                {
                    state = TemplateParserState.SeenRight;
                    break;
                }
                else if (c == null)
                {
                    // We're at the end of the string, nothing left to do.
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.Append(c);
                    break;
                }
            case TemplateParserState.SeenLeft:
                if (c == '[')
                {
                    // This is an escaped left-bracket
                    builder.Append(c);
                    state = TemplateParserState.Plaintext;
                    break;
                }
                else if (c == ']')
                {
                    // This is zero-width parameter - not allowed.
                    var message = Resources.FormatAttributeRoute_TokenReplacement_InvalidSyntax(
                        template,
                        Resources.AttributeRoute_TokenReplacement_EmptyTokenNotAllowed);
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
                }
                else if (c == null)
                {
                    // This is a left-bracket at the end of the string.
                    var message = Resources.FormatAttributeRoute_TokenReplacement_InvalidSyntax(
                        template,
                        Resources.AttributeRoute_TokenReplacement_UnclosedToken);
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
                }
                else
                {
                    tokenStart = i;
                    state = TemplateParserState.InsideToken;
                    break;
                }
            case TemplateParserState.SeenRight:
                if (c == ']')
                {
                    // This is an escaped right-bracket
                    builder.Append(c);
                    state = TemplateParserState.Plaintext;
                    break;
                }
                else if (c == null)
                {
                    // This is an imbalanced right-bracket at the end of the string.
                    var message = Resources.FormatAttributeRoute_TokenReplacement_InvalidSyntax(
                        template,
                        Resources.AttributeRoute_TokenReplacement_ImbalancedSquareBrackets);
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
                }
                else
                {
                    // This is an imbalanced right-bracket.
                    var message = Resources.FormatAttributeRoute_TokenReplacement_InvalidSyntax(
                        template,
                        Resources.AttributeRoute_TokenReplacement_ImbalancedSquareBrackets);
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
                }
            case TemplateParserState.InsideToken:
                if (c == '[')
                {
                    state = TemplateParserState.InsideToken | TemplateParserState.SeenLeft;
                    break;
                }
                else if (c == ']')
                {
                    --scope;
                    state = TemplateParserState.InsideToken | TemplateParserState.SeenRight;
                    break;
                }
                else if (c == null)
                {
                    // This is an unclosed replacement token
                    var message = Resources.FormatAttributeRoute_TokenReplacement_InvalidSyntax(
                        template,
                        Resources.AttributeRoute_TokenReplacement_UnclosedToken);
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
                }
                else
                {
                    // This is a just part of the parameter
                    break;
                }
            case TemplateParserState.InsideToken | TemplateParserState.SeenLeft:
                if (c == '[')
                {
                    // This is an escaped left-bracket
                    state = TemplateParserState.InsideToken;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Unescaped left-bracket is not allowed inside a token.
                    var message = Resources.FormatAttributeRoute_TokenReplacement_InvalidSyntax(
                        template,
                        Resources.AttributeRoute_TokenReplacement_UnescapedBraceInToken);
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
                }
            case TemplateParserState.InsideToken | TemplateParserState.SeenRight:
                if (c == ']' && scope == 0)
                {
                    // This is an escaped right-bracket
                    state = TemplateParserState.InsideToken;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // This is the end of a replacement token.
                    var token = template
                        .Substring(tokenStart.Value, i - tokenStart.Value - 1)
                        .Replace("[[", "[")
                        .Replace("]]", "]");

                    if (!values.TryGetValue(token, out var value))
                    {
                        // Value not found
                        var message = Resources.FormatAttributeRoute_TokenReplacement_ReplacementValueNotFound(
                            template,
                            token,
                            string.Join(", ", values.Keys.OrderBy(k => k, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
                    }

                    if (routeTokenTransformer != null)
                    {
                        value = routeTokenTransformer.TransformOutbound(value);
                    }

                    builder.Append(value);

                    if (c == '[')
                    {
                        state = TemplateParserState.SeenLeft;
                    }
                    else if (c == ']')
                    {
                        state = TemplateParserState.SeenRight;
                    }
                    else if (c == null)
                    {
                        state = TemplateParserState.Plaintext;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        builder.Append(c);
                        state = TemplateParserState.Plaintext;
                    }

                    scope = 0;
                    tokenStart = null;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing the issue to github. I happen to use curly bracket for the route template because I stumble upon conventional routing on my learning path before attribute routing. Conventional routing doesn't seems to support square bracket, so I stick to curly bracket for consistency when learning attribute routing. Am wondering if ASP.NET Core team can make it more consistent?

Comment: Hi @NoctisTong, we can find that Rick did help add `doc-enhancement` tag to the github issue that I reported, we can trace the issue and check if doc team will help update the doc.

Comment: Hi @NoctisTong, the section about "Token replacement in route templates [controller], [action], [area]" in this official doc has updated: *For convenience, attribute routes support token replacement by enclosing a token in square-brackets (`[`, `]`).*